# How to change the country in Samsung Pay?

Tags: samsung-pay

I bought a new Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge in Asia before leaving to France. I now want to use Samsung Pay in France but the app shows Asian ads and notifications in Thai language. I want to know if the app will still work in France, and can you change the original country?

Comment: I've contacted the customer svc and they gave me a really bad answer. Apparently, the Samsung Pay rewards and promo will ONLY reflects the the device origin country. I have no idea if there is anyway to change the origins country data. I hope someone brilliant that experienced this same bad news with me would come up with some flash/ roots solution. As for my case, I ve been collecting the reward points for quite awhile on my note 5 before I change to note 8. And since both devices' origin country isn't the same, I was unable to transfer it. [Edited by Moderator Firelord].

Answer (score 1):

I use an imported Samsung Galaxy S8 from Hong Kong. I wasn't able to change the country that Samsung Pay uses. But I use Samsung Pay in Switzerland with a Swiss credit card. But unfortunately, I get ads from Hong Kong in Hong Kong Dollar.

Once you setup Samsung Pay you can use it worldwide.